# How to detect numbers in string in many observations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to detect all numbers from Name to gain ID. I use this code:

```
  select Name, ID
  from [my_table]
  where [Name] like ('%000234%')
```

But I need that working for many names. I tried Name like in (000234, 000235, ...), but it doesn't work. is it possible to gain whole list of IDs searching by Names?

Comment: You need filter where name is numeric only?

Comment: What do [Name] values really look like. Do you need to use wild cards in your LIKE predicate, (e.g. your names have values in them other than numbers) or can we forego the LIKE predicate altogether and just use a string of numeric characters?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select names for a specific range of numbers

```
select Name, ID
from [my_table]
where [Name] like '%00023[4-9]%'
```

Which will search for names `000234` - `000239`

For other [wild card reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql)

Comment: Unfortunately I have about hundred numbers to search IDs in database. But there aren't subsequent. I can copy paste them into the code but selecting them one by one and run queries is tiring. So I am searching for some codes to ease the process.

Comment: Since your looking for numbers only, you may try `where [Name] like '[0-9][^a-z]%'` which filters only numbers and excludes letters.

Comment: Unfortunately, my previous comment as a mistake, this will yield records whose 1st character is from 0 - 9, the 2nd character is any character that is not a - z whilst the character from hence forth is any character.

Comment: You may try `where [Name] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` which will yield 6 digit name characters.

Comment: my Name is e.g.: 'Shirt S blue N-0000234' and I have plenty of different numbers. I will try to combine with your answers :)

Comment: If you are looking for `Names` with numbers in them, then the filter `where [Name] like '%[0-9]%'` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Insert data to temp table. Then you can merge it with the main table.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (TempName NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TempTable        
VALUES 
('000234'),
('000235')


SELECT 
    A.Name, 
    A.ID
FROM 
    [my_table] A INNER JOIN 
    @TempTable B ON A.Name LIKE '%' + B.TempName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Added test table for clarity.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    NameString varchar(25) )

INSERT INTO #Test (NameString)
SELECT 'Mike387592'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Nancy2387'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Tim0088297234'

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
         NameString
        ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', NameString) AS [Start]
        ,LEN(NameString) AS [End]
    FROM #Test )

SELECT 
     NameString
    ,SUBSTRING(NameString, [Start], [End]) 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a slew of names in a table that have nonsequential numbers that don't have a pattern shared amongst them, one way to gather that data is to use an IN predicate and to dynamically construct your query.

E.G. You want names with numbers 000412, 001523 & 001687.

You would dynamically generate a query like this:

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM [my_table]
WHERE Name IN ( '000412', '001523', '001687' )
```

Dynamic queries could be generated from the database or by the software calling to the database, but are primarily discouraged because they pose a security threat and aren't reusable. Nevertheless, this is an option.

If you must use the LIKE predicate because there are other characters surrounding your numeric string, something like this would be the generated query:

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM [my_table]
WHERE Name LIKE '%000412%' OR
      Name LIKE '%001523%' OR
      Name LIKE '%001687%'
```